# Highchart-graph does not appear in internet explorer

Tags: highcharts

I computed a graph in Highcharts which words perfectly well in any browser but internet explorer (see https://jsfiddle.net/statistik_tg/e69Lp3cv/). I had to add a drill down and drill up as the main chart and the drilled down chart include other metrics. Since then, it hasn't been working in IE.
Does anybody know asolution to let the code run in IE, too? Thanks in advance!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var chart = {
            type: 'column',
            marginBottom: 220,
            spacingBottom: 85,
            events: {
                drilldown: function (e) {

                    if (!e.seriesOptions) {

                        var chart = this,
                            drilldowns = {
                                'Thurgau': {
                                    name: 'Übrige',
                                    color: '#878787', 
                                    data: [
                                        ['2009', 106],
                                        ['2010', 107],
                                        ['2011', 102],
                                        ['2012', 102],
                                        ['2013', 100],
                                        ['2014', 102],
                                        ['2015', 107],
                                        ['2016', 120],
                                        ['2017', 121]
                                   ]
                                }
                        },
                        drilldowns2 = {
                            'Thurgau': {
                                    name: 'Phyisotherapie',
                                    color: '#B5B5B5', 
                                    data: [
                                        ['2009', 79],
                                        ['2010', 83],
                                        ['2011', 82],
                                        ['2012', 85],
                                        ['2013', 89],
                                        ['2014', 103],
                                        ['2015', 115],
                                        ['2016', 128],
                                        ['2017', 132]
                                   ]
                            }
                       },
                       drilldowns3 = {
                            'Thurgau': {
                                    name: 'Laboratorien',
                                    color: '#E39E00', 
                                    data: [
                                        ['2009', 42],
                                        ['2010', 43],
                                        ['2011', 45],
                                        ['2012', 48],
                                        ['2013', 55],
                                        ['2014', 57],
                                        ['2015', 63],
                                        ['2016', 69],
                                        ['2017', 73]
                                   ]
                            }
                       },
                       drilldowns4 = {
                            'Thurgau': {
                                    name: 'Spitex',
                                    color: '#CD3700', 
                                    data: [
                                        ['2009', 48],
                                        ['2010', 49],
                                        ['2011', 53],
                                        ['2012', 58],
                                        ['2013', 62],
                                        ['2014', 68],
                                        ['2015', 75],
                                        ['2016', 80],
                                        ['2017', 83]
                                   ]
                            }
                       },
                       drilldowns5 = {
                            'Thurgau': {
                                    name: 'Pflegeheime',
                                    color: '#8B0000', 
                                    data: [
                                        ['2009', 192],
                                        ['2010', 186],
                                        ['2011', 182],
                                        ['2012', 182],
                                        ['2013', 179],
                                        ['2014', 169],
                                        ['2015', 171],
                                        ['2016', 175],
                                        ['2017', 173]
                                   ]
                            }
                       },
                       drilldowns6 = {
                            'Thurgau': {
                                    name: 'Apotheken',
                                    color: '#FFED00', 
                                    data: [
                                        ['2009', 119],
                                        ['2010', 121],
                                        ['2011', 126],
                                        ['2012', 136],
                                        ['2013', 141],
                                        ['2014', 145],
                                        ['2015', 159],
                                        ['2016', 178],
                                        ['2017', 188]
                                   ]
                            }
                       },
                       drilldowns7 = {
                            'Thurgau': {
                                    name: 'Ärzte Laboranalysen',
                                    color: '#00B4E8', 
                                    data: [
                                        ['2009', 52],
                                        ['2010', 45],
                                        ['2011', 46],
                                        ['2012', 47],
                                        ['2013', 51],
                                        ['2014', 54],
                                        ['2015', 58],
                                        ['2016', 61],
                                        ['2017', 62]
                                   ]
                            }
                       },
                       drilldowns8 = {
                            'Thurgau': {
                                    name: 'Ärzte Medikamente',
                                    color: '#0064e6', 
                                    data: [
                                        ['2009', 339],
                                        ['2010', 331],
                                        ['2011', 327],
                                        ['2012', 329],
                                        ['2013', 335],
                                        ['2014', 330],
                                        ['2015', 342],
                                        ['2016', 361],
                                        ['2017', 369]
                                   ]
                            }
                       },
                       drilldowns9 = {
                            'Thurgau': {
                                    name: 'Ärzte Behandlung (ohne Labor)',
                                    color: '#27408B', 
                                    data: [
                                        ['2009', 477],
                                        ['2010', 490],
                                        ['2011', 509],
                                        ['2012', 521],
                                        ['2013', 563],
                                        ['2014', 586],
                                        ['2015', 632],
                                        ['2016', 646],
                                        ['2017', 655]
                                   ]
                            }
                       },
                       drilldowns10 = {
                            'Thurgau': {
                                    name: 'Spital ambulant',
                                    color: '#a2c510', 
                                    data: [
                                        ['2009', 474],
                                        ['2010', 481],
                                        ['2011', 524],
                                        ['2012', 533],
                                        ['2013', 579],
                                        ['2014', 597],
                                        ['2015', 602],
                                        ['2016', 658],
                                        ['2017', 675]
                                   ]
                            }
                       },
                       drilldowns11 = {
                            'Thurgau': {
                                    name: 'Spital stationär',
                                    color: '#3CA433', 
                                    data: [
                                        ['2009', 724],
                                        ['2010', 733],
                                        ['2011', 736],
                                        ['2012', 727],
                                        ['2013', 874],
                                        ['2014', 865],
                                        ['2015', 844],
                                        ['2016', 833],
                                        ['2017', 793]
                                   ]
                            }
                       },
        series = drilldowns[e.point.name],
                        series2 = drilldowns2[e.point.name];
                        series3 = drilldowns3[e.point.name];
                        series4 = drilldowns4[e.point.name];
                        series5 = drilldowns5[e.point.name];
                        series6 = drilldowns6[e.point.name];
                        series7 = drilldowns7[e.point.name];
                        series8 = drilldowns8[e.point.name]; 
                        series9 = drilldowns9[e.point.name]; 
                        series10 = drilldowns10[e.point.name]; 
                        series11 = drilldowns11[e.point.name];
                        chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series); 
                        chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series2);
                        chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series3);
                        chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series4);
                        chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series5);
                        chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series6);
                        chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series7);
                        chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series8);
                        chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series9);
                        chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series10);
                        chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series11);
                        chart.applyDrilldown();
                        chart.yAxis[0].update({
                            min: 0,
                            max: 4000
                        })
                }
            },
            drillup(){
                this.yAxis[0].update({
                min: 0,
                max: 100
              })
            }
        }
    };

        var plotOptions = {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal'
                    }
        };
        var title = {
            text: "Fast die Hälfte der Kosten im Kanton Thurgau für Spitalbehandlungen",
            style: {
                fontSize: '18px',
                },
            align: 'left'
        };

        var subtitle = {
            text: 'Struktur der Bruttokosten nach Kostengruppe, Kanton Thurgau und Schweiz, 2017, Anteile in %/CHF pro versicherte Person¹',
            style: {
                fontSize: '12px'
                },
            align: 'left'
        };      

        var yAxis = {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            title: '',
            lineWidth: 1,
            max: 100
        };

        var xAxis = {
            type: 'category'
        };


        var tooltip = {
            valueSuffix: ' CHF' 
         };

        var series = [{
            name: 'Übrige',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'  
            },
            color: '#878787',
            data: [{
                name: 'Thurgau',
                y: 3.7,
                drilldown: true
            },{
                name: 'Schweiz',
                y: 3.5,
                drilldown: false
            }]
        },{
            name: 'Physiotherapie',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'  
            },
            color: '#B5B5B5',
            data: [{
                name: 'Thurgau',
                y: 4.0,
                drilldown: true
            },{
                name: 'Schweiz',
                y: 3.1,
                drilldown: false
            }]
        },{
            name: 'Laboratorien',
            color: '#E39E00',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'  
            },
            data: [{
                name: 'Thurgau',
                y: 2.2,
                drilldown: true
            },{
                name: 'Schweiz',
                y: 2.8,
                drilldown: false
            }]
        },{
            name: 'Spitex',
            color: '#CD3700',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'  
            },
            data: [{
                name: 'Thurgau',
                y: 2.5,
                drilldown: true
            },{
                name: 'Schweiz',
                y: 2.7,
                drilldown: false
            }]
        },{
            name: 'Pflegeheime',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'  
            },
            color: '#8B0000',
            data: [{
                name: 'Thurgau',
                y: 5.2,
                drilldown: true
            },{
                name: 'Schweiz',
                y: 5.7,
                drilldown: false
            }]
        },{
            name: 'Apotheken',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'  
                },
            color: '#FFED00',
            data: [{
                name: 'Thurgau',
                y: 5.7,
                drilldown: true
            },{
                name: 'Schweiz',
                y: 11.8,
                drilldown: false
            }]
        },{
            name: 'Ärzte Laboranalysen',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'  
                },
            color: '#00B4E8',
            data: [{
                name: 'Thurgau',
                y: 1.9,
                drilldown: true
            },{
                name: 'Schweiz',
                y: 1.7,
                drilldown: false
            }]
        },{
            name: 'Ärzte Medikamente',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'  
                },
            color: '#0064e6',
            data: [{
                name: 'Thurgau',
                y: 11.1,
                drilldown: true
            },{
                name: 'Schweiz',
                y: 6.3,
                drilldown: false
            }]
        },{
            name: 'Ärzte Behandlungen (ohne Labor)',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'  
                },
            color: '#27408B',
            data: [{
                name: 'Thurgau',
                y: 19.7,
                drilldown: true
            },{
                name: 'Schweiz',
                y: 22.6,
                drilldown: false
           }]
       },{
            name: 'Spital ambulant',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'  
                },
            color: '#a2c510',
            data: [{
                name: 'Thurgau',
                y: 20.3,
                drilldown: true
            },{
                name: 'Schweiz',
                y: 19.1,
                drilldown: false
           }]
       },{
            name: 'Spital stationär',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'  
                },
            color: '#3CA433',
            data: [{
                name: 'Thurgau',
                y: 23.8,
                drilldown: true
            },{
                name: 'Schweiz',
                y: 20.7,
                drilldown: false
            }]
        }];

        var drilldown = {
            series: []
        };


         var legend = {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            padding: 25,
            symbolPadding: 10,
            symbolWidth: 25,
            margin: -10,
            /*maxHeight: 150,*/
            alignColumns: false,
            reversed: false,
            itemStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'normal'
            }
        };

        var credits = {
            text: '<b>Hinweis: Für den Vergleich der Kostenanteile im Kanton Thurgau von 2009-2017 klicken Sie <br><b>auf den Balken oder die Balkenbeschriftung zum Thurgau<br>¹ Vergleich Thurgau-Schweiz Anteile in %, Vergleich Thurgau 2009-2017 Anteile in CHF<br>Dienststelle für Statistik Kanton Thurgau <br>Datenquellen: Bundesamt für Gesundheit, Monitoring der Krankenversicherungs-<br>Kostenentwicklung',
            href: false,
            style: {
                color:'#999999',
                cursor: false,
                fontSize:'10px'
            },
            position: {
                align: 'left',
                x: 10,
                y: -90
            }
        };
        var exporting = {
            allowHTML: true,
            enabled: true,
            filename:'2019_07_Krankenversicherungskosten_Brutto_2017',
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    menuItems: "printChart separator downloadPNG downloadJPEG downloadSVG".split(" ")
                }
            },
            /*csv: {
                columnHeaderFormatter: function (item) {
                    if(item instanceof Highcharts.Axis) {
                        return 'Quartal';
                    } else {
                        if(item instanceof Highcharts.Series) {
                            return item.name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }*/
        };

        var responsive = {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 500
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }]
        };

        var highchartsOptions = Highcharts.setOptions ({
            lang: {
                decimalPoint: '.',
                thousandsSep: "'",
                months: ['Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember'],
                weekdays: ['Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag'],
                shortMonths: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mrz', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
                contextButtonTitle: 'Drucken, Download, Export',
                downloadJPEG: 'Download JPEG Bild',
                downloadPNG: 'Download PNG Bild',
                downloadSVG: 'Download SVG Vektor Bild',
                downloadXLS: 'Download XLS',
                printChart: 'Bild drucken',
                viewData: 'Datentabelle ein-/ausblenden',
                resetZoom: "Zoom zurücksetzen",
                resetZoomTitle: "Zoom zurücksetzen",
                drillUpText: "Zurück",
                numericSymbols: null //otherwise by default ['k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E']
            }        
        });

        colors = ["#878787","#B5B5B5","#E39E00","#CD3700","#8B0000","#3CA433","#a2c510","#FFED00","#00B4E8","#0064e6","#27408B"]

        var json = {};
        json.chart = chart;
        json.plotOptions = plotOptions;
        json.title = title;
        json.subtitle = subtitle;
        json.yAxis = yAxis;
        json.xAxis = xAxis;
        json.tooltip = tooltip;
        json.series = series;
        json.drilldown = drilldown;
        json.legend = legend;
        json.credits = credits;
        json.exporting = exporting;
        json.responsive = responsive;
        json.highchartsOptions = highchartsOptions;
        json.colors = colors;

        $('#2019_07_Krankenversicherungskosten_Brutto_2017').highcharts(json);
    });
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you elaborate on what you mean by "it isn't working" in the question rather than relying on someone having IE and having to run it.

Comment: The code does not run when I implement it i.e. in htlm-editor like https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default in IE, but runs when I do the same in i.e. Chrome...

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: No errors there.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in IE developer tools console - you need to change JS line 230 from this:

```js
drillup(){
```

into this:

```js
drillup: function() {
```

and then it [works fine in IE11](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3j2enu0t/embedded/result,css,html,js)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint, works perfectly now :).

Kind regards